# Creating user account & pasting files in Desktop remotely?

Tags: users

I need to create a separate user account in all the systems. And I have to paste a few files in their desktop. I have created a separate user account with a password remotely. However, when I type ls `/home/username` only `examples.desktop` file is shown there. There is no Desktop, Music, Videos, Documents Folder etc. I know after logging in to that account physically the system creates a folder for new users automatically. But is there any other way to achieve this? I need to create a user account for more than 200 systems.

#### Update:

- The clear solution will get a bounty.

#### Update 1:

- Accessing the system via SSH.
- Yes, the user account must have a password.

Comment: If there is no solution for this, I suggest you let the ubuntu-devs know, that there is a need for this function in the terminal (launchpad). I don't think you're the only one that needs this.

Comment: You access the systems with passwordless ssh?

Comment: Yes i access all the systems with passwordless ssh..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this an *answer-in-progress*, since more details are necessary on how you are adding users, whether it's the same username, etc.

---

Assuming you are creating a user with the same name and the same *Desktop* contents on each of the 200 systems, you need to do the following:

1. Pack the custom "Desktop" contents into a tarball, and upload it somewhere. Example:

   - Suppose the `Desktop` folder and other custom home contents are in `/home/karthick/custom-folders`
   - Archive with `cd ~/custom-folders && tar -cvzf ../customfiles.tar.gz .`
   - Upload `customfiles.tar.gz` to e.g. some HTTP server, say `http://personal.karthick.com/`
2. Here's the outline of the script to run on the target system to create the user with the custom folder:

   ```
   sudo useradd --create-home customuser
   cd /home/customuser
   wget -O- http://personal.karthick.com/customfiles.tar.gz | tar -xz
   sudo chown -R customuser:customuser *
   ```

---

More information that would be helpful to improve the answer:

- Are you setting a password for this user? Will it be the same user?
- How are you accessing the remote systems - SSH?

Comment: Please add the information requirement as comment in the question. It would make it easier to spot and get a speedy answer.

Comment: Please see the updated information in my question..

Comment: I will try your method and if i face any problems i will let you know. As my bounty expires in short period i am aloting it to you :)

Comment: @karthick87: Thanks; sorry that I missed your updated comment yesterday. If you face any issues, I think we could resolve it much faster via an AU chatroom :) . In any case, please do let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Ubuntu are you using? In any case, upon creation of a user account, the contents of `/etc/skel/` are copied to the user's new directory. I the usual user folders are not in `/etc/skel` they will not be in the new user directories either.

In that case, you might want to write a script that creates the user you need and then the folders inside their directory. It seems easier to me, rather than editing the contents of `/etc/skel` in 200 systems.

Comment: Well, if there is no smarted method, and if your `/etc/skel` doesn't contain those directories, I guess you have to go with a scripted method.